# Как не повторять декларацию переменной, импортируемой в другой файл с использованием ключевого слова extern?

Tags: c, gcc, stm32

Если в основном файле объявлена переменная:

```
uint16_t     ADC;
```

То для использовании ее в другом файле нужно ее объявить снова с использованием ключевого слова `extern`:

```
extern uint6_t    ADC;
```

Проблема этого подхода в том, что во-первых много лишнего кода, а во-вторых если в основном файле поменяется, например, тип, то это исправление нужно вручную делать по всем другим файлам. Особенно "весело" когда переменная не такая простая как в моем примере, а какой-нибудь юнион структур строк на 5-10. Ну и вероятность ошибки при этом возрастает многократно.

Что-то тут не так. Принцип DRY (Don't repeat yourself) точно не удовлетворяется. Есть ли способ более изящно кодить в таких случаях?

Если использовать подход с заголовочным файлом, то как быть в этом случае? Допустим есть файл `main.c` и `yetanotherfile.c` и переменная, объявленная в `main.c` должна быть использована в `yetanotherfile.c`. То как это делать? Предположу:

Файл `main.h`

```
extern uint16_t                ADCres;
```

Файл `main.c`

```
uint16_t                       ADCres;

void main(void) {
    ADCres = 1;
}
```

Файл `yetanotherfile.c`

```
#include 'main.h'
void yetanotherfunction(void) {
    if(ADCres == 1)
        // Do something weired
}
```

Так?

Comment: про заголовочные файлы не слышал? так вот, объявление с внешним связыванием обычно выносится в них ;)

Comment: @Fat-Zer слышал :)))) Но что-то я слабоват в технике многофайловых проектов. Я дополнил свой вопрос, вы не могли бы взглянуть, правильно я там написал?

Comment: В main.h добавляете ее как раз как extern, так как это требуется во всех файлах проекта. А там где переменная непосредственно содержится пишите уже в .c файле без extern.

Comment: @Mike подправил. Правильно?

Comment: @RomanMatveev, да, всё правильно... только не забудь добавить стражи включения, дабы в будущем не иметь проблем с множественным/рекурсивным включением хедеров...

Comment: @Fat-Zer т.е. все-таки двойной декларации не избежать? Один раз в главном файле и один раз в хедере с `extern` ?

Comment: @RomanMatveev, да, так устроено связывание в Си: каждая единица трансляции компилируется абсолютно независимо, поэтому должна содержать объявления всех используемых идентификаторов. Хедер файлы по сути просто подставляются вместо `#include` и дают возможность избежать перечисления всего списка переменных в каждом файле... в принципе можно макросами свести объявления/определание к одной единственной строчке, но это не поощряется и имеет свои проблемы...

Answer (score 1):

Можете воспользоваться препроцессором:

`header.h`:

```
//...
#ifndef ADCRES_DEFINITION_UNIT
extern 
#endif //ADCRES_DEFINITION_UNIT
uint16_t                ADCres;
//...
```

`main.c`:

```
#include "header.h"

//здесь будет extern uint16_t ADCres;
```

`def.c`:

```
//Задаем этот макрос либо с помощью #define, 
//либо при компиляции данного файла, например, в makefile
#define ADCRES_DEFINITION_UNIT
#include "header.h"

//Здесь будет определение
```